# Group n documents with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

I habe a large set of documents that look like this

```
   {value: 13, date: 2017-28-01 12:00:01, channel: A}
   {value: 14, date: 2017-28-01 12:00:01, channel: B} 
   {value: 138, date: 2017-28-01 12:00:02, channel: A} 
   {value: 11, date: 2017-28-01 12:00:12, channel: A} 
   {value: 17, date: 2017-28-01 12:00:09, channel: C}
   ...
```

The query I am looking for should split every channel in groups of 3 elements (sorted by date) and return the average value and date for each group.

The result should look like this

```
[
      {average: 54, average_date: 2017-28-01 12:00:05, count: 3, channel: A},
      {average: 12, average_date: 2017-28-01 12:00:06, count: 3, channel: B}
      {average: 90, average_date: 2017-28-01 12:00:15, count: 3, channel: A},
      {average: 561, average_date: 2017-28-01 12:00:05, count: 3, channel: C},
]
```

Just like having buckets that can contain three elements and only elements of the same channel can be put into one bucket.

This aggregation will be used to only display a certain amount of values on a line diagram.